# How to change mavenLocal path in gradle android

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-3

I am working mavenLocal repository in android,I am running gradle install command in android studio it is creating m2 repository inside users/username but i want this repo in custom path.I changed maven settings.xml localrepository path still it is placing user folder only

Command:

```
./gradlew install
  <localRepository>${user.home}/Desktop/Some/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

Comment: so... you changed a maven settings file and you expect gradle to know about it? That's not how it works sorry

Comment: i got answer https://www.codenotfound.com/maven-change-location-local-repository.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [system property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties) `maven.repo.local` to point to your new location.